# Can we always reduce the weights of a weighted graph to rationals and preserve equality relationships?

Tags: graphs, simulation, weighted-graphs

Let $G = (Q, \Delta, W)$ be a *finite* weighted graph with $\Delta: Q \times Q$ and $W: Q \times Q \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Is it the case that there always exist a function $W': Q \times Q \to \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ such that $\forall S, S' \subseteq Q, \forall s, s' \in S$:

$$
\sum_{s'' \in S'}{W(s, s'')} = \sum_{s'' \in S'}{W(s', s'')} \Leftrightarrow \sum_{s'' \in S'}{W'(s, s'')} = \sum_{s'' \in S'}{W'(s', s'')}
$$

?

I believe, at least for the finite case, this should be possible and I'm trying to prove this "constructively" by finding $W'$.

So let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ be a rational such that $\forall s_0,s_1,s_2,s_3 \in Q, \epsilon < |W(s_0, s_1) - W(s_2, s_3)|$ whenever that difference isn't $0$.

Obviously if we just round every non-rational weight in a grid with spacing $\epsilon$ we will not preserve equalities and I believe it'll be quite difficult to restore the exact relations.

So my idea is to round one weight at a time, and then fix the equalities that get broken by modifying only non-rational weights and repeating the process until there are only rational weights.

So start by taking two subsets $S, S' \subseteq Q$ and take $s \in S$ and $s'' \in S'$ such that $W(s, s'') \notin \mathbb{Q}$.
Now we can round this number to the nearest rational of the form $k\cdot \epsilon$.

Let $e = W(s, s'') - W'(s, s'')$ is the error we introduced.
Now if there was an $s' \in S$ and an $s'''$ such that $W(s', s''') = W(s, s'')$ then we modify that weight in the same manner, and thus the iff condition still holds for $s$ and $s'$.

Otherwise for $s' \in S$ we must have that some (more than one) weight $W(s', s''') \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and we can subtract $e$ from it and preserve the condition for $s$ and $s'$ with respect to $S$ and $S'$.

However we have now changed some other weight, and thus while we may have preserved the equality between $S$ and $S'$, we may have broken it for other subsets. So we have to consider every subset that is either a subset or superset of $S$ and $S'$, verify if we have broken that *iff* condition, and if so we must find an other weight and change it, and repeat the process until it we find an equilibrium. But does this actually happen?

My question is:

1. Does there exist such $W'$ or am I trying to build a non-existent function?
2. If $W'$ exists, is the above approach feasible in some way, or should I completely change strategy in order to find $W'$? Do you know any particular trick that can help in devising $W'$?

Comment: Use a Hamel basis.

Comment: What is $\Delta$? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer The edge relationship. There is an edge between $s, s' \in Q$ iff $(s, s') \in \Delta$.

Answer (score 3):

Identify $W$ with the set of all weights. Let $B$ be a basis of $W$ over the rationals. That is, you can write every weight in $w$ as a linear combination of elements of $B$ with rational coefficients. You can identify the weights with vectors $\vec{w}$ of length $|B|$. Each linear dependency that you want to avoid can be thus encoded as an inequality
$$
\sum_i \alpha_i b_i \neq 0,
$$
where the coefficients $\alpha_i$ are not all zero. We can moreover assume that the $\alpha_i$ are integers (by taking a common denominator).

Let $M$ be an integer larger than all $|\alpha_i|$ appearing in an inequality you are interested in. If we replace $b_i$ with $M^i$ then all the requisite inequalities will be satisfied, while all *equalities* will also be preserved.

Comment: Cute! Probably useful to note that finding $B$ isn't really constructive (imagine $W=\{1,\pi, e, \pi+e\}$) but those seem like pretty silly weights to put on a graph anyways.

Comment: So $W'$ would become something like $W'(s, s') = \sum_{i}{\alpha_i M^i}$? Also is there a more constructive solution? For example: assume you have an oracle that tells you whether a weight $w$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}$ or not. Is that enough to obtain an algorithm that computes $B$ as in your answer or for finding a different solution?

Comment: @Bakuriu For a constructive solution you need a way to find all linear dependencies. What you wrote isn't enough.